Sufficient condition for an attaching space to be Hausdorff
In Dieck's Algebraic Topology, it is claimed without proof:

Proposition 1.2.4. The space $Y \cup_f X$ is a Hausdorff space, provided the following holds: $Y$ is a Hausdorff space, $X$ is regular, and $A$ is a retract of an open neighbourhood in X.

This has been proven in, e.g., Brown's Topology and Groupoids for the case when $A$ is closed. It is not clear to me how to modify the proof for when $A$ is not closed.
Is the proposition true? If so, how?

You don’t say what $f$ and $A$ are, but any retract of an Hausdorff space is closed

Good point, but then $A$ is closed on the open neighborhood $N$, not necessarily on $X$.

tom Dieck is implicitly assuming that $A$ is closed in $X$. I believe that the statement of the proposition is intended to be read together with the sentence which directly proceeds it. Here is a counterexample to the general case:
Let $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Take the inclusion $A\subseteq X$ and Let $f:A\rightarrow Y$ be also the inclusion. Then $X\cup_AY$ is the line with two origins, which is $T_1$, but not $T_2$.

@FernandoChu $A$ is open in $X=\mathbb{R}$. It is trivially a retract of itself.

Oh oops, you're right!
